# Control 12v lock switcher with Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino, 12v

I have 12v poser supply for electronic lock. It has 3 valuable pins: **+12V**, **GND** and **PUSH**. So, when I want to unlock the lock, i need to push **PUSH** pin to **GND**. How can I push 12v line to ground with Arduino Nano?

Comment: You can likely just use a MOSFET.  For a definite answer, you should provide a link to a datasheet or product page for the electronic lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A definite answer isn't possible without more information about the lock.  You likely want something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDF27V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Drive IOPIN HIGH to ground the PUSH pin.

Many other parts could be used in place of the IRLML2502. It's convenient for driving directly from an IO pin. Whether you need the flyback diode D1 depends on the lock.

Comment: Yes, exactly what i need!

Comment: Why I cant connect IOPIN to PUSH directly and send logical 0 (push to GND), or 1 (push to +12V)?

Comment: If you did that, the IO pin of your Arduino Nano would sink whatever current flowed out of the PUSH pin of your lock. They can probably only sink about 30mA (check the datasheet), but the lock may source much more than that. Without more information about the lock, it's impossible to say. It probably does, and the result would be permanent damage to your Arduino.